# How do I change the color of the Simulink scope graph given that a condition is true?

Tags: matlab, scope, simulink

I have a simulation in Simulink that has a scope in it and is my primary result. It simulates the voltage of a system. I would like to highlight the region in the graph where the voltage is below a certain level (compare to constant is true).

Is there a way to change to color of the Simulink Scope to start drawing in e.g. red, once a condition is true?

Comment: You could have a scope with 2 identical inputs layered on top of each other. Set one signal to zero unless condition is satisfied, set the other to zero unless condition isn't satisfied. Will look like the same signal with different colours.

Comment: I tried it and it does what I want it to do, however it doesn't connect the two lines which looks really ugly when there is a high gradient. But thanks anyways.

Comment: You could offset the conditions forward & backward by one sample to join them, but it's still a bit of a hacky workaround. You might be better exporting the data to your workspace and using Matlab's more flexible plot tools.